# Need help understanding strange array syntax

Tags: java, arrays

I found this bit in a book and I don't get what it does:

```
int index = 1;
...
getArray() [index=2]++;
```

*[index=2]++;* looks strange to me, but compiles. What's weirder is that it becomes Invalid if *++* is removed, even though as far as I can tell, *++* does nothing in this case (the value is always 2).

So, what's the point of the post-increment operator in this case (since it doesn't increment the value), why the brackets and why is the statement legal only if post-inc is added at the end?

Can someone explain what this mysterious syntax is and what it does?

Comment: `++` will increment one of the array elements.  Did you check those?

Answer (score 12):

Let's break that code:

```
getArray() [index=2]++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int[] someArray = getArray();  // Assume that's an int[]
index = 2;
someArray[index]++;
```

The last line is equivalent to:

```
someArray[index] = someArray[index] + 1;
```

If you remove that `++`, then the 2nd expression is not a valid statement. It just becomes:

```
getArray() [index];
```

You have to assign that to some L-Value.

Comment: That's awesome. What do you mean by "L-Value"?

Comment: @aliteralmind Left-Value. Means, some variable to store the value of that array index.

Comment: @RohitJain your "is equivalent to"s are wrong. In the original, `index=2` occurs after `getArray()`, so you've got the assignment to `index` and the evaluation of `getArray()` the wrong way round. I've written a [demo of the difference](http://ideone.com/dNSHOU). The first should be `int[] arr = getArray(); index = 2; arr[index]++;` (and the second one is then redundant).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will be invalid, you're not doing anything with it.

```
getArray() [index=2]++;
```

For demonstration i will switch `getArray()` with `myArray` which has `{ 100, 200, 300, 400 }`.
Than it's equals to:

```
myArray[2]++;
```

`myArray[2]` will now output: 301
And `index` will be: 2

Answer (score 0):

`getArray()` must return an array of numbers (let's say `int`s), so `getArray() [index=2]++;` dissected:

```java
int index = 2;
int[] array = getArray();
array[index] = array[index] + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package test1;
public class Q30 {
    private static int[] x={10,20,30};
    public static int[] getArray(int[] y) {
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 1;
        getArray(x);
        for (int q:getArray(x)) {
            System.out.print(q+" ");//10 20 30 
        }

       // try {
        getArray(x)[index = 2]++;
        //} catch (Exception e) {
        //}  //empty catch
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("index = " + index);//index = 2
        for (int q:getArray(x)) {
            System.out.print(q+" ");//10 20 31 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).